# Electron frameless window.open with default menubar

Tags: javascript, css, electron

Hi I am trying to create a help menu with links to documentation in electron. I would like to know if it is possible to create a new window with the default menubar from within a frameless window. I am currently using the following.

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://electron.atom.io/docs/','electron')">documentation</button>
```

If my current window is not frameless then the window will be created with the menu.

Comment: Did you try `window.open('https://electron.atom.io', 'Electron', 'chrome=0,status=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0,location=0');`?

Comment: That didn't quite work window.open('https://electron.atom.io', 'Electron', 'frame=true'); did however  I only figured it out by looking at your example. I was using : where I should have used =. The documentation didn't really specify how to set the features all it said was window.open(url[, frameName][, features]) so I was wrecking my head trying to get it to work with { [

Comment: Oh good. I must has misread the question before. I added an answer with links to the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the option `frame=0`.

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://electron.atom.io/docs/', 'electron', 'frame=true')">documentation</button>
```

See [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) docs for more, specifically [window features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features)